# Find $\vec{x}$ if $[\vec{x},\vec{a}]=\vec{b}$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, cross-product

I have $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. Need to find $\vec{x}$ if $[\vec{x},\vec{a}]=\vec{b}$

---

Let $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)$. Then $[\vec{x},\vec{a}]=(ya_z-za_y;za_x-xa_z;xa_y-ya_x)=(b_x;b_y;b_z)$
We have the system, where $a_x,a_y,a_z,b_x,b_y,b_z$ we know:
$$ya_z-za_y=b_x$$
$$za_x-xa_z=b_y$$
$$xa_y-ya_x=b_z$$
(right?)

---

How to solve it (Find $x,y,z$)

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions if $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=0$. There are no solutions if $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\neq 0$.

Comment: @A.Goodier In what case would $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\neq 0$ be true? Since $\vec{a} \times \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ dot product of a and b would always be zero.

Comment: The question is to find $\vec{x}$ given $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$: if $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\neq 0$, then such an $\vec{x}$ does not exist.